# True or false : The homogenous system has only the trivial solution since the number of equations is the same as number of unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

The homogeneous system

```
  x + y +  z = 0
 2x - y - 2z = 0
-5x + y + 3z = 0
```

has only the trivial solution since the number of equations is the same as number of unknowns. How do I prove or disprove this?

Comment: Fisrt you check if the [Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is zero or not. Check the wikipedia page to see which conclusions arrive in each case, but note this is rather simple, and you don't need to read this whole page.

Comment: Does the system $x+y=0; 2x+2y=0$ have only the trivial solution?

Comment: You can have a system like $x+y=0$ and $2x+2y=0$. This are linearly dependent equations. So it might  (will) have other solutions.

Comment: The reasoning that it has only the trivial solution *because* the number of equations equals the number of unknowns is fallacious as John Bates has already pointed out.  To know whether or not this system has only the trivial solution, all you have to do is solve the system.

Answer (score 0):

After doing Gaussian elimination (a.k.a. row reduction) we obtain that this system of linear equations is equivalent to:
$$x+y+z=0$$
$$y+\frac{4}{3}z=0$$
so it has solutions other than the trivial one, e.g. $(\frac{1}{3},-\frac{4}{3},1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Row reduction:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & -2 \\
-5 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets R_2-2R_1\\R_3&\gets R_3+5R_1\end{aligned}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -3 & -4 \\
0 & 6 & 8
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{R_3\gets R_3+2R_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -3 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you finish?